# handling various frame layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm new to game development and am trying create a Contra or the old tmnt game (but a simple one) like game for android. for the game i decided  to divide my main screen in three parts - upper for stats,mid for the game and lower for controls.
my main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/upper_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" >
</FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/low_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.85" >
</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

so i have created the gameview and gameloopthread classes for the mid surface(which is pretty standard). my problem is that how do i draw in the upper and lower frame layouts?
should i make new classes for view and thread for each layout , should i do all this in the gameview class itself or is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: For game development, its better to use a gaming engine like andEngine.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference to that layouts doing this:

```
FrameLayout upper = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.upper_bar);
upper.addView( yourCustomView );

FrameLayout lower = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.low_bar);
lower.addView( yourCustomView );
```